# Visual Studio Editor Classifier Override

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

I'm working in VS2012 and I'm creating a new editor classifier. Basically, I'm very disappointed with Microsoft's Typescript syntax highlighting, so I wanted to add to it. But I'm having hard time overriding their default colors. I can override certain keyword colors (like `public` or `var`) but I can't override others (like `this` or `static`).

The way you're supposed to be able to adjust it is through the `Order` attribute on the exported classes.

```
[Order(Before = Priority.High)]
internal sealed class ETS_Keyword : ClassificationFormatDefinition { ... }
```

There are two order attributes that you can include (`Before` and `After`) and three priorities (`Default`, `Low` and `High`). I swear I've tried every combination of the them, but I can't seem to override the default colors on some of the keywords (and probably other classes of items).

Is there something special that I need to do to override these classes? I know I'm fighting with the default Typescript extension, but there has to be a way to be at a higher priority level than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, my sincerest apologies. I can't believe this, but this issue didn't have anything to do with priorities. It turns out that I was editing my regular expression to match new keywords, but Visual Studio wasn't re-compiling my project before debugging in the Experimental Hive (unlike my VS2008 and VS2010 installations).

So I guess if you're having this issue, try using your IDE correctly. :/